# Unsuccessful HTTP POST Request to Rails Application

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, post, request

I unsuccessfully attempted to send an HTTP POST request from a Java application running on Windows to a Rails application running on a virtual machine on the same computer.  Below is both the HTTP POST request from the Java side and the code to receive it on the Rails side.The error that I receives (on Java's Eclipse IDE) was "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect"

Can someone please help me to understand where I am going wrong and specifically what I can do on the Rails side to receive the post request.

This is the Java HTTP POST Request:

```
public void sendHTTPPOSTRequestReport(int c, int s){

try {
    //*****************************************************************************************
    //JSON Object Created Here
    JSONObject reportObject = new JSONObject();
    reportObject.put("student_id", myClass[c].getStudentElement(s).getStudentNumber());
    reportObject.put("student_name", myClass[c].getStudentElement(s).getName());
    reportObject.put("school_name", getSchoolName());
    reportObject.put("instructor_name", getInstructorName());
    reportObject.put("course_name", myClass[c].getClassName());
    reportObject.put("absent_days", String.valueOf(myClass[c].getStudentElement(s).getAbsences()));
    reportObject.put("tardy_days", String.valueOf(myClass[c].getStudentElement(s).getTardies()));
    reportObject.put("total_grade", String.valueOf(myClass[c].getStudentElement(s).getTotalGrade()));

    JSONArray assignmentArray = new JSONArray();

    for(int a=0; a<20; a++){

        JSONObject assignmentObject = new JSONObject();

        assignmentObject.put("assignment_name", myClass[c].getAssignmentElement(a).getName());
        assignmentObject.put("assignment_date", String.valueOf(myClass[c].getAssignmentElement(a).getDate()));
        assignmentObject.put("assignment_category",myClass[c].getAssignmentElement(a).getCategory());
        assignmentObject.put("assignment_score", String.valueOf(myClass[c].getAssignmentElement(a).getGrade()));

        assignmentArray.add(assignmentObject);
    }
    reportObject.put("assignments", assignmentArray);
    System.out.println(reportObject);
    //*******************************************************************************************

    //Base64 Conversions
    //name:password converts to bmFtZTpwYXNzd29yZA==
    //“name:password” converts to Im5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQi
    String basic = "Im5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQi";//HTTP Basic Authentication


    String hostname = "192.168.80.2";//This is the static IP of the virtual machine.
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
    int port = 80;
    Socket socket = new Socket(addr, port);

    String path = "http://0.0.0.0:3000";

    BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));
    wr.write("POST"+path+" HTTP/1.0rn");
    wr.write("Authorization: Basic "+basic+"\r\n");
    wr.write("Content-Length: "+((CharSequence) reportObject).length()+"rn");
    //wr.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencodedrn");
    wr.write("Content-Type: application/json");
    wr.write("rn");
    // Send parameters
    //wr.write(obj);//This was the format from an example but had to be modified as follows:
    reportObject.writeJSONString(wr);
    wr.flush();
    // Get response
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    wr.close();
    rd.close();
    socket.close();//Should not close this socket but leave it open until program closes
}catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

This is the code on the Rails side:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "name", password: "password"

  def index
    render plain: "Text Goes Here!"
  end

  def edit
    render plain: "Text Goes Here."
  end

end
```

Comment: To begin with, use a framework that leverages doing this work instead of using plain Sockets.

Comment: Could you please be more specific.

Comment: There are other frameworks like [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) that ease sending HTTP calls through the net, so you don't have to use Sockets and that stuff (in Java side). Apart of that, maybe your Webrick (or the app server) where you host your ROR app is not started, the app is not deployed or your pointing to the wrong url. You can make sure of this by using another tool to send a HTTP call like curl besides using the Java code.

Comment: Thanks.  I will check the url and read about Apache HttpComponents. I thought that using Sockets was necessary in order to send a post request to an application running on the same computer.

Comment: and you should query to 192.168.80.2:3000 i guess.

Comment: Do you mean that I should change to String path = 192.168.80.2:3000;